# How do I do a optional chaining on const? | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know it's a dumb question but i can't do it.

This is my code.

```
taggedUser ?
const reported = new reportModel({
      _id: mdb.Types.ObjectId(),
      User: taggedUser.username,
      UserId: taggedUser.id,
      rByUser: message.author.username,
      rByUserId: message.author.id,
      rReason: args[1]
    });
:
message.channel.send("Didn't find user")
```

And I can't do it. Can someone help me? I'm new to this.

Comment: What are you doing with `reported` after?

Comment: Using an other module, don't worry about it.

Comment: You're trying to use a *statement* inside an expression.  Expressions can only contain other expressions.  `const reported = ...` is a JS statement.  But the conditional expression (sometimes called the ternary) punctuated with `?` and `:` is an *expression*.  There are many ways of correcting this, from switching to `if-else` to  a better work-up of your data structure, but I don't think we can help without additional details: Does this `reported` object get passed back to some calling function?  Do you ignore it and keep processing when it doesn't exist?  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chaining operation is not needed. You can simplify it to be like this:

```js
if (!taggedUser) message.channel.send("Didn't find user")

const reported = new reportModel({
   _id: mdb.Types.ObjectId(),
   User: taggedUser.username,
   UserId: taggedUser.id,
   rByUser: message.author.username,
   rByUserId: message.author.id,
   rReason: args[1]
})
```

> Use chaining operations if you need a return value from the comparison. Use `if else` if you need to control the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Statements cannot be used inside expressions.

You can create a `reported` variable and `buildReportModel()` function just above `taggedUser`, to assign new `reportModel` to `reported` when `taggedUser` is `true`

```
let reported;

function buildReportModel() {
  reported = new reportModel({
    _id: mdb.Types.ObjectId(),
    User: taggedUser.username,
    UserId: taggedUser.id,
    rByUser: message.author.username,
    rByUserId: message.author.id,
    rReason: args[1]
  });
}

taggedUser ? buildReportModel() : message.channel.send("Didn't find user");
```

Comment: I'd suggest that is an inappropriate use of the conditional expression.  It should be used to determine a value, and not for side effects like setting the `reported` variable or calling that `send` method.  `if-else` is much more appropriate.

Comment: I agree with you @ScottSauyet